# awk space delimiter with empty content

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file which is delimited by space

```
1 dsfsdf 2
2  3
4 sdfsdf 4
5 sdfsdf 5
```

When I run

```
awk -F' ' '{s+=$3} END {print s}' test
```

It returns 11. It should return 14. I believe awk gets confused about the second line, between two spaces nothing there. How should I modify my command?

Thanks

Comment: Use `$NF` to get the value of the last field on the line instead of using `$3`?

Comment: Use `awk -F' {1}' '{s+=$3} END {print s}' test`

Comment: This is just an example, my file has four columns. I want to sum up the third column.

Comment: Escape the space `awk -F'\\ '` or `awk -F'[ ]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
awk -F' {1}' '{s+=$3} END {print s}' test
```

you get

```
14
```

**Note**

if test file contains

```
1 dsfsdf 2 1
2  3 1
4 sdfsdf 4 1
5 sdfsdf 5 1
```

also it works, i use gnu-awk

**edit**

how, @Ed_Morton and @"(9 )*" says is better to use literal space `[ ]`

```
awk -F'[ ]' '{s+=$3} END {print s}' test
```

Comment: from comment "９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９" also can be used `awk -F'\\ '` or `awk -F'[ ]'`

Comment: There's no need to use an RE interval (which will not work in older gawks nor in nawk) for this, just tell awk to use a literal blank char - `awk -F'[ ]' ...`.

Comment: @EdMorton Still though why doesn't `-F' '` work? Does the space have a special meaning when in a field separator?

Comment: @user000001 yes, it's the default value and it does have a special meaning - it means "fields are separated by contiguous sequences of all white space characters after all leading and trailing white space is trimmed off". It's not when it's **in** a field separator, though, it's when it **is** the field separator.

Answer (score 1):

this should work too if only the second column has missing values.

```
awk '{s+=$(NF-1)} END{print s}'
```